# How can I use column values as column names in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, categories

I have a table that looks like this:

```
|date      |category_id|val
|2010-08-09|1          |2
|2010-08-09|2          |45
|2010-08-10|3          |1500
|2010-08-10|2          |4
```

I would like to select from this table, that each category id is a column so the end result looks like this:

```
|date      |1    |2   |3 
|2010-08-09|2    |45  |NULL
|2010-08-10|NULL |4   |1500
```

Is something like this possible with a single `SELECT` statement or stored procedure, without using an extra table and without knowing all category_id values beforehand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql query to dynamically convert row data to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599788/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-row-data-to-columns)

Comment: YES, but it would require scripting to build out your SQL-Select statement, but don't have MySQL readily available to build such simulation of a Cross-Tab resultset

Comment: What you're describing is known as transposing, cross-tabulating, or pivoting. Not sure if you can do this with a single SELECT, at least not in MySQL without another language doing some work for you. Check out this article for some ideas: http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2003/12/04/crosstabs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use MYSql's `sign` to do this.  Here is a good link that does something very similar to what you are tryign to do:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Comment: While I still need to know what values I have in the category_id column, this solution is easy enough to generate the SQL SELECT with a small script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.

http://www.futhark.ch/mysql/106.html