# Can you do a For Each Row loop using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My question is related to the answer found in this post by user **Consultuning on Oct 22 '09 at 18:31**:
[mysql query to dynamically convert row data to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599788/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-row-data-to-columns)

It appears that **Consultuning's** answer contains some MySQL with a `For Each row` loop.

Can you do a `For Each Row` loop using MySQL?

If so, could someone give me a link to the MySQL `For Each Row` documentation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The closest thing to "for each" is probably [MySQL Procedure using Cursor and LOOP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html).

Answer (score 5):

Not a for each exactly, but you can do nested SQL

```
SELECT 
    distinct a.ID, 
    a.col2, 
    (SELECT 
        SUM(b.size) 
    FROM 
        tableb b 
    WHERE 
        b.id = a.col3)
FROM
    tablea a
```

Answer (score 2):

In the link you provided, thats not a loop in sql...

thats a loop in programming language

they are first getting list of all distinct districts, and then for each district executing query again.

Comment: I guess my question should be, Can you do a `for each row` loop using mysql?

Comment: as far as i know, u can't do that via pure SQL.
The link u r referring to in ur comment is basically explanation of the nested query join algorithm.
it simple explains how MYSQL fetches data when there is a join involved on two columns. @zechdc

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So really I need to be using a `join` to get something similar to a `for each`