# Create a view by using row data as column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table like the following:

```
---------------------------
| Timestamp | Value | Name|
---------------------------
| 12345678  | 2     | abc |
---------------------------
| 12345678  | 3     | abc |
---------------------------
| 78910111  | 4     | cde |
--------------------------
| 56789101  | 1     | abc |
---------------------------
| 56789101  | 2     | cde |
---------------------------
```

I need to transform it into something like this:

```
-------------------------
| Timestamp | abc | cde |
-------------------------
| 12345678  |  5  |  0  |
-------------------------
| 56789101  |  1  |  2  |
-------------------------
| 78910111  |  0  |  4  |
-------------------------
```

Where values in the above table are sums for a particular Name at a particular timestamp
the names in the lower table are not known and can be dynamic. I need a SQL query to do this.

Comment: Found a related article, that provides some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599788/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-row-data-to-columns

Comment: what if you have 1000+ Name in the table ?

Comment: While there is an upper limit of column rows that needs to be watched. If that is not really an issue (you are going to have comfortably less than 1000 columns) and you want to do this dynamically then you need to be looking at Dynamic SQL (for SQL Server) PL/SQL (for Oracle), etc. What system are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transpose rows into columns in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943496/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try following query:-

```
SELECT timestamp, SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'abc' THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS abc,
SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'cde' THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS cde
FROM tab
GROUP BY timestamp;
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a721f4/8

Comment: The Names are not known before hand and can be more more than 2.